# Creating a new directory in c#

Tags: c#

I would like to first create a new dir and then save a file into the following location C:\Users\Paul\Documents + \newfolder\nameOffile.xml.

Can this be achieved in C#. I currently have the following code but i cant seem to get it to work

```
    XDocument doc = new XDocument(rootNode);
    var dateAndTime = DateTime.Now;
    var date = dateAndTime.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
    var patWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    string savedFilePah = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments));
    var savedFile = savedFilePah + "/" + Directory.CreateDirectory("newFolder") + "/" + patWithoutExtension + "_" + date + ".xml";
    //var savedFile = "C:/tmp/" + patWithoutExtension + "_" + date + ".xml";
    doc.Save(savedFile);
    lblFileUploaded.Text = "Success!";
```

it keeps failing on the doc.save with the following error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException'
>   occurred in System.Xml.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not find a part of the path
>   'C:\Users\Paul\Documents\newFolder\test2_29-03-2015.xml'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify the full path to the directory you want to create, otherwise it's created at the working (running) folder:

```
string myDocs = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
var myDir = Path.Combine(myDocs, "newFolder");
Directory.CreateDirectory(myDir);
var savedFile = Path.Combine(myDir, patWithoutExtension + "_" + date + ".xml");
```

Comment: @Paul, btw, per MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/54a0at6s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx you can delete the unnecessary check for directory existance, I've edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be with `Directory.CreateDirectory("newFolder")` which will create the folder under the working directory rather than under `C:\Users\Paul\Documents`.

Also, as a good practice I would advice to store the newly created folder in a dedicated folder. The advantages of this are twofold - you'll be able to watch this variable easily during debugging thus find out the exact location of the created folder and also, if an exception will be thrown you'll know the exact location of it.

Also, some Windows APIs might not accept a forward slash ('/') but will except a backslash ('\').

Answer (score 0):

This `Directory.CreateDirectory("newFolder")` is not creating the directory inside your Users folder: you're just passing it `"newFolder"`, so it doesn't know that's where you want the folder. It will be creating it in your current working folder (e.g. `bin/Debug`).

Try passing the entire path to `CreateDirectory`:

```
string savedFilePath = Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments),
    "newFolder");
Directory.CreateDirectory(savedFilePath);
```